# Obtain variables in function from other function C++

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to pass a variable from one function to another. I have tried this approach but it is not working for me:

```
int c (){
    int x1,x2,y2,y1;
    system("cls"); 
    cout<<"Insert Value"<<endl
    cin>>x1;

    return x1;
}

int cd()
{
     int a;
     a=c();
     cout<<"X1: "<<a;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Indentation, it matters.

Comment: Please show us the class or code that is using this.  At this point I only see two methods and nothing calling them.

Comment: Flushing is important.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code.

First of all you are missing a semicolon after the `cout` statement in your `c()` function.

Also you have indicated that function `cd()` should return an `int` but you are not returning anything.

Lastly, these function will not begin execution unless you call them explicitly.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int c (){
    int x1,x2,y2,y1;

    cout<<"Insert Value"<<endl;
    cin>>x1;

    return x1;
}

int cd(){
     int a;
     a=c();
     cout<<"X1: "<<a;
     return a;

}

int main()
{
    int x=cd(); //call the function to create the side effects

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, I have demonstrated why elimination of his compile time errors (missing semicolon and function return value) can fix the problem. Oops, looks like you deleted your comment